# Remember and restore WPF window's scren, WindowState and position?

Tags: c#, wpf

As part of my application settings, I store the last position on the workspace of the window and it's WindowState. I can successfully restore the position, even on another screen, but one thing I can't... Maximize the application on a non-primary screen.
So, if my application closes when maximized on screen 2, I want to restore it maximized on screen 2.
How do I do this?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question

Comment: It happens very often...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it in the loaded event. See:
http://mostlytech.blogspot.com/2008/01/maximizing-wpf-window-to-second-monitor.html

Comment: Make sure you do it in the `SourceInitialized` event instead of `Loaded`. Otherwise it'll flicker, looking rubbish.